# Is 8 Ball Pool from Miniclip Legal According To Islamic Teachings

Tags: practical-islam, fiqh, game, gambling

As-salamu alaykum  my Brothers and Sisters in Islam. I have a question that Is 8 Ball Pool from Miniclip Legal According To Islamic Teachings. Its a online game i play and one day a close relative pointed out that it could be considered as gambling. If you aren't familiar with the game it's a simple game of pool however both players give in a certain amount of game money to play Game moneyis earned through various ways through out the game including winning matches and earning daily bonuses etc. So can anyone please help me in guiding whether such a game is wrong or not. Hopping You are Well and Thank You in Advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What kind of games are permissible and forbbiden?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/43245/what-kind-of-games-are-permissible-and-forbbiden)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Are Video Games halal or haram?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/29062/are-video-games-halal-or-haram)

Answer (score 2):

Asalamualaikum Brother... As far as real money is not involved & your niyyat (intentions) are not of gambling, One cannot consider it Haram at all. Its just a game with nothing wrong.
Its all virtual money/coins so you are good. JazakAllah

Answer (score 1):

With great respect, I am not Muslim but have found interest in the popularity of players from Muslim regions so I googled it and found this link. I understand that sometimes money may indirectly be involved but I do not believe any players can cash out. Without the cash out I don’t think we can consider it gambling. It’s purchasing credits to play.

I’m not trying to incorage Muslims to play if they feel otherwise. I’d just like to say I enjoy the diverse experience of playing the game with  so many from varied backgrounds. Peace

Comment: Quick question, how are the 'credits to play' purchased? Does it involve real money or is it based on a waiting time to increase one's 'game stamina'?

Answer (score -1):

IT is haram just because it is virtual doesn't mean it can happen things like this do happen and you know gambling online real or fake it is still doing the same thing as the pool points include Cash And Coins

Just cause it's fake doesn't mean it can make one gamble in real life

Answer (score -1):

Yes, It's Completely prohibited, bcz its include real money. There is option of buying coin, spinning and earn money involve real money.

If you even don't buy coins, you not surely know that your opponent is not spending money.

And We Know...If there is little chance of haram, it's not to be done.

I leave playing...when I got comment, I lost my 7$.

Answer (score -2):

Asalamualaikum my dear brothers 
In the quran it is clear that gambling is haram 
Meaning that anyway or source. Harmful or not .if it is something that ALLAH subhanahuwataala has restricted you from doing it than it is for your own good. AND i have a very good example 
One of my muslim friends played it alot until one day shaytaan took over him and he started to do sport betting on pool,soccer,basketball games 
we as his friends tried to explain him and even gave him proofs from the quran. but he didnt listen.
My suggestion is that stop playing it otherwiswe u are going against your ALLAH and his simple and straight forward rules.
Jazakalah
Wasalamualaikum