# Are Video Games halal or haram?

Tags: halal-haram, music, game

After exploring the internet, I just got more confused with these questions....

What kind of video games, science fictions, nobles, stories and music are halal in Islam?

Comment: Why do muslims always ask for "halal or haram" and never want to think: "Is it good for me or anybody, even if it was halal?"

Answer (score 3):

As a general rule it should not be Haaram, as it's not mentioned as Haaram in Quran or Sunnah direcctly (unless those contains such things that are already accepted as Haaram e.g., Nudity, gambling, music, looking towards faces of non-maharrams, etc).

But another very important consideration for a Mu'min (as this question bore in your mind, that means you are aware and want to remain safe from wrath of Allah) is the pleasure of Allah.

Now ask yourself, is these games anyway help you remembering Allah, or those help in opposite way. See, we are here in this world for very short time [see **Qur'an: 18:19; 23:99,113**] and we should more engage in worship, rather than engaging in events that make us forget our purpose.

The Prophet (saw) advised to: "***Take benefit of five before five: Your youth before your old age, your health before your sickness, your wealth before your poverty, your free time before you are preoccupied, and your life before your death***"
(Narrated by Ibn Abbas and reported by Al Hakim)

"***Everything other than remembering Allah is (considered) wasteful play except four: a man humoring his wife, a man training his horse, a man walking between targets (learning archery), and man learning swimming***" narrated by An-Nasaa'i and authenticated by Al-Albaani (Sahih Al-Jami' 4534).

So, as a thumb rule, anything that take you to confusion should be avoided, if you want to remain safe.

Al-Hasan bin 'Ali said: "I remember that the Messenger of Allah (s.a.w) said:
'***Leave what makes you in doubt for what does not make you in doubt. The truth brings tranquility while falsehood sows doubt***.'" [Jami` at-Tirmidhi Vol. 4, Book 11, Hadith 2518]

Comment: Thanks brother, for your help. Actually I'm a very young man. Maybe this is why I can't understand th hadith about archery, not even any kind of sports and swimming. Can you please explain it in the perspective of a 16 years old? I mean, I don't do archery but I do study on various subjects (mainly science)  and do a lot of programming and science experiments and crafting beside my school work, I'm a fish keeper and animal lover. So, among what are haram among the things I have described above? It'll be a really big help if you explain. Thank you again.

Comment: My opinions may not be scholarly... I'm also a programmer. What I may suggest (I personally try to adopt) that, try to relate every act of yours to Akhira (here-after). We need sports and refreshments (Islam doesn't prohibit that). But, those things/actions/events that totally take away ones attention, forgetting regular things and kill times should be avoided, eg, playing cards, computer games, movie, music, chess, cricket, etc. Some sports of physical hardship may be played to keep oneself fit (those are encouraged, and does not kill time- as a man can't do physical hardship for long time).

Comment: And brother, reading science, I can't forbid you, but what we more need is to study the wonder book, the ultimate guide, the Quran. You will see.. if you regularly establish 5 times salah, and engage some time to know the shariah and Islam (reading Quran, Hadiths with meaning), you will have very less time to engage in unnecessary things.

Comment: But here is a problem, I read in a school in Dhaka, Bangladesh. But it starts a t 12. And ends 5.30. Then coaching starts at 5.30, when I come home, it is almost 9. So, when its night,, I try to upgrade my skills to those activities I like and can make a good and halal career out of it. But before doing the crafting or other hobby stuff I think about it, that will it help me to have a good or halal career or not. And, in the morning, I have to study, at night, I'm tired. So at night, I do stuffs that can give some relief from stress I.e. programming, looking at my pets or doing science stuff.

Comment: Science, pets and animals really makes me amazed to see beauty and the power of Allah SWT. To be honest, I have started trying to become a mum'in only a few days ago. So it is a bit hard for me to understand the difference between good and bad in the eye of Islam.

Comment: So, now I'll keep myself away from gaming, music and movies. But another question, is gossiping with friends or mahrams haram?

Comment: Gossiping is not haaram, if those does not involve any haram things. Rather if it make your friends happy, bias towards Islam, that is a act of worship. Thing is, you have to make a balance, society is important, but not at the cost of Imaan.

In islam, choosing friend has also importance. Try to have those kinds of friend, who remind u of akhira, avoid those friends who encourage u to dunia. [You can see Quran 2:113, 257; 3:28, 118; 4: 119, 139, 144; 5: 51, 80; 7: 27, 30; 8: 72, 73; 9:16, 23, 67, 71, 123; 18: 28 (important); 58: 14, 22; 60: 1, 4, 9, 13]

Comment: And regarding pets... Dogs are strictly forbidden other than only purpose of Guarding house, store, etc

Answer (score 0):

Based on Shia view, Music's that are used for or known as(by the same man or people who know art) vulgar are banned.

so music's that are or contain sex, nudity and stuff like that are haram.
but it's okay to be in a place that this kind of music in public places or Hall's and every where you don't have control over the music being played.

and for the games, novel's same rule applies, you should not read or play game's containing sex, nudity and stuff that are  considered as disrespect to religion's...

as i assume you are Sunni, i stop there and post some links for further readings:

Games:
[sistani](http://www.sistani.org/persian/qa/0841/), [other Shia clerics](http://www.hawzah.net/fa/Magazine/View/4892/6908/83258/%DA%A9%D8%AF%D8%A7%D9%85-%D8%A8%D8%A7%D8%B2%DB%8C-%D9%87%D8%A7-%D8%AD%D8%B1%D8%A7%D9%85-%D8%A7%D8%B3%D8%AA%D8%9F)

Music and other Multimedia:
[Khamenei](http://farsi.khamenei.ir/treatise-content?id=99), [Siatani](http://www.sistani.org/persian/book/53/241/)

Comment: Yeah brother or sister (actually I don't know) I'm a Sunni. Well, can I play games like, 0ad, age of empires, dota 2, NFS rivals or battle field 4? There are killing enemies, but no other thing as you stated above. But background music is enabled. And can I listen to music's that are written on environment and politics or country? (I couldn't translate the pages)

Comment: will the only problem i have seen Shia cleric's make with this kind of games is, the thing they call as soft war these games pull of by calling Muslim's as terrorist's... and that problem i see as an political problem not religious... because i haven't seen other cleric's out of Iran, like mr Sistani make any calls about these games being haram or banned...

Comment: @senaps Oh, and if a Gta game does not contain: nudity and sexual things, then it is halal to play gta? Or, it is permissible to play as long as it is less violence?

Comment: @AlexA if it's not about killing other people or muslims, they are okay with it. here in iran we have war games approved by the shia clerics.

Comment: @senaps Oh, so even though in gta games, they are added Mosques and so on with condition not to be included nudity and sex?

Comment: in gta game, you are killing and driving over people witch is violence and in some cases is considered bad. but if you are Shia, you should check with the cleric you follow. for the best answer. cause they have different opinions on that. if sunni, will i don't know anything about their thought's on this matter.