# Is video games haram

Tags: halal-haram, game

Assalamu'Alaikum.

I want to ask something about video games. If I play a video game that has nothing haram in it and I don't play a lot but abount 2 to 3hrs a day. But I wanted to know if this falls under doubtful matters because it may lead to bigger sins? I noticed I get thoughts about that video game during prayer specifically... even though I am trying hard to not think about it.

So if someone can tell me, is this something haram since it effects my prayer? I don't really have any other activities I can do outside, or any friends nearby. So if this is haram, and suggestion of what can be done for having some recreation time?

May Allah (SWT) guide us. AMEEN.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Are Video Games halal or haram?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/29062/are-video-games-halal-or-haram)

Answer (score 0):

Alslam alikum brother / sister. I am going to tell you a story and leave the judgment for you. Once the prophet [pbuh] promised his compniens in one of the prayers that if they can do khosho' (not think about anything but the prayer and Allah) they will get a big rewerd. And the compniens actually did it untill the last part of the prayer where they started to think of what reward they will get and that destroyed their khosho'.

So in my opnion as a human it is nearly imposible to not think during a prayer. BUT you can't let these thoughts distract you during the prayer what i found helpfull is taking refuge from shaytan whenever i get these thoughts and subhan allah these thoughts disappears directly.