# Is making tiktok gaming videos haram

Tags: halal-haram

I was wondering if making tiktok gaming videos haram because someone told that I can make a vidoe but not long enough because it will waste the viewers  time

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Are Video Games halal or haram?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/29062/are-video-games-halal-or-haram)

Answer (score 0):

**Bismillah Hir Rahmaan Nir Raheem**

**As Salaamu 3laykum,**

As long as you are not playing games that have animate beings and not wasting time. Then I don't see any issue with it.

There are ahadith that state about the prohibition of making pictures and those would translate into moving objects as well. All pc games what I know of use 3d imaging from computer based software.

There is an ayah in the Quran (chapter 25 verse 67)

"And [they are] those who, when they spend, do so not excessively or sparingly but are ever, between that, [justly] moderate" Translation: Saheeh International

I understand it states in terms of money however there are other ayahs that show wasting in terms of other resources. And time is above these things when it comes to resources so then it would be to reason that we should not be wasteful in it.

**Have a nice day!**