# What kind of games are permissible and forbbiden?

Tags: halal-haram, game

I’m curious to know if I can play the following games: Gta V(5) the most popular game, Gta San Andreas, Gta vcs and lbs, Jak 2 And 3, clash of clans, clash royal, blackjack, Minecraft, Red dead redemption and 8 ball pool? And can I play billiard on real life?

Minecraft is a non violence game and it is peaceful, it all about how to have a creative mind and to have fun only.

Black jack it has,none realistic money so It contains false money not real one.

When I started to play Gta V, I wanted to visit a strip club and I saw only boring stuff and I decided to never go there. The only thing I like in the game is, that I can drive any car, I can take any aircraft and fly, and do many cool stuff. Is it ok how I did? And is that true that if one plays these games he/ she must not play too much so that the brain will no get affected and corrupted?

And why would it be forbidden for someone to play a game that contains living thing and statues and gambling?

“Of course”, I don’t worship a statue from a game, why would it be then forbidden? Violence I know it is but I can play these game rarely not all the time because there are other important things like: praying and studying for going to University that I wished to go. “Because”,  the purpose of these games are just to have fun for having relaxation. And even if I play *grand theft auto San Andreas*, I still pray and study in school.

Can any the best experts of Islam to answer me? “Because”, I would like to hear also from others.

Comment: I play games, but I think you are asking for fatwa. in this case, this website is not the place for that, I suppose.

Comment: Games per se are makrooh as a waste of time.

Comment: @Medi1Saif then if then are a waste of time,then What is the purpose for them?I mean they are made so that we can fun,right?

Comment: That's a question which is not related to Islam. The point is if something keeps you away from dhikr Allah and prayer it is makrooh or haram

Comment: @Medi1Saif Aha,so if I play these games that I mentioned and I pray in Islamic way then it is no longer waste of time or haram,right?

Comment: No i don't think so,  except if you could define the islamic way.tw

Comment: @Medi1Saif in Islamic way I meant on the way that Muslims pray to God and never leave their obligations,on that I reffered

Comment: @Medi1Saif like in the beginning of prayer to stand with head down with 2 hands on belly and then to bow and say the prayer and etc

Comment: @Medi1Saif In Islamic way,I meant on obligatory prayers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any games which helps in jihad for the sake of Allah are mustahabb to play.
The Prophet (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him) said: ***“Shoot, O Bani Adnaan, for your father was an archer.”***

Also, anything which is free of:

- gambling, violence, dice (reference: *Sunan an-Nasa'i 5088*)
- obstacle to obligatory remembrance of Allah
- involving statues, images of humans , accompanied by music

Also, the game should not take up, because then there is a fear that the ayah: ***“Who took their religion as an amusement and play, and the life of the world deceived them. So this Day We shall forget them***” [**al-A’raaf 7:51**] may become applicable to him.

References:
Go through: https://islamqa.info/en/22305

So, no, you should not play any of the games you mentioned since those games either depict human imagery, or violence. However, you can play 8 ball pool.

Also, please go through this: https://islamqa.info/en/2898

Comment: **<comments deleted>** Comments are intended for constructive criticism and seeking clarification for the purposes of improving the post. They are not for tangential discussion or chatting; if you want to chat, take it to [chat].

Comment: Why is playing Minecraft, haram? It is not even violent, but a peaceful and creative game.

Comment: And, is that true that if a person plays a gta game for a short period and then he pray more and study in school more, then there is nothing wrong with playing this kind of game? Or still it is haram, no matter what?

Answer (score 0):

As-salamu alaykum

---

Games which has image of human and animals are haram as they are creations of Allah Ta'ala. As well as games which do not have any images of humans or animals but has haram activities such as violence, gambling etc etc are also considered haram. Gta v is a game with a image of human and there is no single halal things you can find. So its haram if you even play it a little or even if you study and pray well and consider play this game its still haram.

---

May Allah bless you