# Is killing people in video games haram?

Tags: halal-haram, game

> I play a game called **PUBG** where you have to **kill other players who are**
>   **not on your team**. I play this game when I get bored. It does not
>   affect my salat(prayer). I go to mosque regularly. It does not affect
>   my studies also. So, is playing such games in such conditions haram or
>   halal?

I know questions about video games are already asked several times. But, I need an appropriate answer on **"killing player in video games halal or haram"**.

Comment: Two huge issues here: (a) Why would you think it's haram in the first place? (b) If this question has already been asked several times already, what was unsatisfactory about those answers?

Comment: Actually in those answers I didn't find that killing players in "video games is halal or haram" - exceptionally this topic. I've already checked all questions but didn't find any answer. Could you please answer this question?

Comment: @goldPseudo I am really in a trouble in this matter. If you can kindly give an answer of this question I will be very satisfied. Just don't put it on hold and please let other to answer this question. This question is not similar to all other question on this topic. A huge group of people don't know this answer. I hope either you will answer this or you will remove the on hold topic.

Comment: You've provided absolutely no reason to believe this would be haram in the first place. Even if I were to re-open it right now, it's just going to end up a duplicate of https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/36838/22.

Comment: Can this be a question reformulated as "*Are shooting games allowed?*"?. But, it could still be a duplicate of this [question](https://islam.stackexchange.com/a/43723/11938).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First playing games per se is rather frowned upon in Islam as it is a waste of time and may disturb you from your duty of the daily prayers.

Secondly playing games depicting humans is widely discussed in several questions on the site which generally come to the conclusion it is haram.

Thirdly assuming the game is nevertheless "halal" killing in a game doesn't count as a sin per se. As you don't kill in reality. However depending on the age of the "gamer" this could have some negative impact on his personality (at least this topic is widely discussed among specialists from education and psychology).

Comment: But games...depicting humans as a problem of "tasweer" may not be since, games that models characters either don't look human, or aren't modeled that realistic. Most of the time, the characters eyes, face and nose are not vissible. Unless that if one plays a realistic high spec games. But for that, the character r usually modeled based on a real individual. The real individual seems looks animated in the game and all the acting done by that individual is recorded into the game.

Comment: @EPICTubeHD you cannot have your own interpretation of Islam. Islam is Islam's interpretation. period.

Comment: eh I don't think I am giving my own interpretation here tho. It's not like there's a clear cut interpretation on the issue of tasweer in Islam. There's many interpretations.

Comment: @EPICTubeHD if you want to address a user use "@" depicting people as declared haram in Islam starts from giving a pictured individual head, arms and hands it is not necessary to depict his face fully (it is enough that none would doubt it being a face of a living being) nor body in detail such as five fingers each hand.

Comment: @Medi1Saif yes as far as I know drawing or keeping images/statues of hyperrealistic or detailed creatures as in you can't distinguish if the picture or real, is wrong. I may be mistaken but that's what I know. Whereas correct me if I am wrong, cartoons or sketches and stuff doesn't show any realism hence it's ok. Although I know this particular topic is quite in a difference of opinion

Comment: @EPICTubeHD you are certainly wrong as the preislamic deities certainly were not that realistic and these are one of the reason sculptures and drawings of living beings are haram.

Comment: @Medi1Saif I see. In that case...why was it stated that our prophet was happy or smiled at Aisha (RA) when she was playing with dolls. I mean, given your logic those dolls weren't realistic and our prophet would have been angry at Aisha rather than happy. So are there exceptions or contexts under which the ruling of tasweer applies?

Comment: @EPICTubeHD that's not my logic. Dolls are explicitly halal toys for girls. My own logic is that a person who doesn't believe that he creates a human by drawing or forming a figure is not committing shirk, but might cause others to regard his work as a creation which is somewhat an issue. I'd even wouldn't regard playing such games an issue as long as there's a pedagogical goal behind the game play.

Comment: @Medi1Saif So what exactly is your argument. From what you have mentioned it seems like you are saying that when someone say draws or sculpts that has any resemblance to an animate creature be it a stick figure or a cartoon or even a realistic portrait isn't in error, as long as the one creating it isn't creating with the intension of challenging Allah or isn't in the belief that he is creating an actual creature. Correct me if I am wrong. Cuz I am trying to reconcile the ruling for little kids playing with dolls and the ruling of tasweer in islam.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116005/discussion-between-epic-tube-hd-and-medi1saif).

Answer (score 1):

no it is not haram because exaple see you can play fortnite there is killing but not human beigns if it was haram they would bann it from muslim countries simple so play but do not miss prayer

Answer (score 0):

I think its not good to play shooter games , i am straightly not saying this haram , i also used to play Counter Strike , i dont play it anymore , the thing that is important is in your salah if you're thinking about the game .

Answer (score -2):

It is not haram because you don’t kill people in real life.

Comment: Assalamualaikum wa rahmatullahi wa barakatuh, welcome to Islam stack exchange, we really appreciate your contribution please take your time to visit [answer] for more information on how to answer a question

Answer (score -3):

I don't think it's Haram because you kill but no one in real life is being killed and no one is dead.

Comment: it's haram. you're not allowed to play games in Islam

Comment: @abdullahsaid who said games aren't allowed? What's your proof/evidence of such a claim?

Comment: first, it wastes your time from doing ibada. second, it contains haram content sometimes, like drawing of creatures, exposing character body. mimicking Allah's creation.

Comment: @abdullahsaid not all games are like that though. And not all games are addictive to the point you lose focus on other parts of your life.

Answer (score -3):

It distroy your time, those time you use way to islam, now a days we need some active Muslim becouse we are lage behind.

Comment: Assalamualaikum wa rahmatullahi wa barakatuh, welcome to Islam stack exchange, we really appreciate your contribution please take your time to visit https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-answer for more information on how to answer a question