# is it haram to play shooting games like fortnite call of duty and more shooting games

Tags: halal-haram, game

I play a game called fortnite and we know that killing is haram right so does it mean shooting games is haram

Comment: can anyone answer to my question

Comment: Thanks for asking your question, but its been 14 minutes since you asked your question only. Sometimes it takes time to get a great answer. Any effort for prior research to asking would have been appreciated, but this should answer your question: https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/52213/is-killing-people-in-video-games-haram?rq=1. And feel free to read the steps of writing a good question from our Help Center: https://islam.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Tho some say it’s haram or makrooh killing someone in a game dosent count (halal killing) I’m just as confused but I’m not sure it’s alright or not just don’t miss daily prayers and don’t make it habit.

Comment: and i might say it could be haram because i've seen on google that some people say it's halal and some people say it's haram

Comment: I never miss daily prayers i never make it as a habit

Comment: can anyone please answer to my question