# Am I sinful if I play games that have killing

Tags: halal-haram, sin, game, doubts

I am concerned about a game that involves killing and I play this game am I sinful or is this just makrooh

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is killing people in video games haram?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/52213/is-killing-people-in-video-games-haram)

Comment: So it’s makrooh because it says the sin doesn’t count I’m just confused

Comment: it's better not to play those games since they're violent and we Muslims should surround ourselves with peace.