# Are games allowed?

Tags: sharia

As Salam alaikum. I'm playing a game based on the anime "Naruto" one of its names is "The Hijutsu conflict". By the type of card game. There is nothing like a generation from the word at all. But the names of some modes in the game, for example, "Ninkai Domination". That is, just this type of name. You can download and watch. Is it a shirk and a sin that I play it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What kind of games are permissible and forbbiden?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/43245/what-kind-of-games-are-permissible-and-forbbiden)

Comment: Look also at https://islam.stackexchange.com/a/12451/55518

Comment: What makes you think it is shirik, and not only haram?

Comment: I really need an answer